# Set an object to a Backbone.js model without having to call "set()" on every property

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

To set the data within a Backbone collection:

```
var someList = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
collection.reset({models:someList});
```

Is there a way to do this with a `model` without having to call `set()` on every single property?

**Example**

```
var pop_star = {
    first_name: "Stacey",
    last_name:  "Ferguson"
}
// There is no "reset()" function on a model, but is there something like it?
model.reset(pop_star);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually is the [Model.set()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) what you're looking for. It can receive a `hash` and it will update only the attributes into the hash.

```
model.set(pop_star);
```